# How could a minimal sample return only from the plumes of an ice moon, Ceres or Io be designed?

Tags: probe, mission-design, sample-return, plume

Would it be feasible and would it make sense to minimalistically design a sample-return-only mission (or class of missions) along these lines:

- Light weight plume collecting aerogel (like the Stardust mission) as the only science instrument payload.
- No payload to communicate with Earth. Trajectory correction (if necessary) done autonomously based on minimal sensors and propulsion system.
- Battery as the only energy resource. Deep sleep mode almost all of the time.
- Return trajectory formed by gravity assist at Jupiter or Saturn.
- Earth based radar locates it when it returns, an Earth orbiting spacecraft docks with it and lands it on Earth.

The main ideas being that other kinds of science are best done by an orbiter or a fast flyby. A sample return needs a different kind of trajectory than all the other instruments. Also, since it returns physically, radio communication is not necessary.

EDIT:
**Actually, why not send ONLY a sheet of aerogel? Nothing else, no propulsion, no electronics, no energy source, no heat source. And a whole series of them to improve chances of success.** Are such trajectories possible without any correction by the probe?

Comment: The chances of getting back w/o any corrections are very slim. 10^-7 downwards.

Comment: @Deer Hunter, but if there's flexibility in the collection of the sample upon return, then both the target (plume, ring, upper atmosphere, comet tail) and the collection space are quite large. Flexibility on return should be helped by the fact that the aerogel with sample has very very low mass. Collection from return trajectory to Earth surface seems to be the big problem here.

Comment: The other problem is what to do when it 'returns' - if we could aim it perfectly to re-enter Earth-orbit, then we need another mission to dock with it to extract the samples. More risk, more cost. 

This is one reason why most probes to the analysis in-situ and beam back the data. Electrons are easier to capture and can be re-sent.

Comment: @john3103 I optimistically assume that the aerogel with samples could be (released from other spacecraft parts, if any, and) caught by a high speed interception with a spacecraft on an economical Earth landing return trajectory. By compressing the aerogel it could be landed in a small Earth reentry capsule, and the (rest of the) collection spacecraft could be reused multiple times. I think there are three important points here: 1) The very low mass of aerogel and samples. 2) The special trajectories needed for a sample return. 3) Physical return instead of radio transmissions.

Comment: Check this out: http://new.livestream.com/viewnow/exploremars/videos/49463207 Pete Worden of NASA Ames mentions in the video Interplanetary Cubesats capable of achieving Δv of up to 10 km/s using SEP. But this what you describe in the question has actually been done before with [Cassini sampling ice water spray plumes of Enceladus](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Space_Science/Cassini-Huygens/Cassini_samples_the_icy_spray_of_Enceladus_water_plumes), with the only difference of these samples not being returned back to Earth. A light craft like cubesat with workable Δv budget could do it tho.

Comment: NASA's [Stardust mission did return samples](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/1815/49) from comet Wild 2's coma tho, using aerogel particle collector. More info e.g. here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stardust_%28spacecraft%29#Sample_return